# what is difference between obo, bio2rdf and bioportal

Tags: ontology, semantic-web

why people should use obo format instead of rdfs. Also, I want to understand the difference between obo foundry, bio2rdf and bioportal.
Are there any similarities between them?

Comment: I am not aware of any "rdfs" format. RDF schema is basic schema suitable for any RDF dataset, and OBO is built for RDF.